# Trouble Saving object and Child Objects to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-4.5

I am having trouble to see what i need to correct or add to my controller in order to have my data saved to the database. See below what i have so far.

**Create method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Team model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            new Team
                {
                    Name = model.Name,
                    Division = model.Division,
                    Description = model.Description,

                    TeamContact = new TeamContact
                                        {
                                            EmailAddress = model.TeamContact.EmailAddress,
                                            PhoneNumber = model.TeamContact.PhoneNumber,

                                            TeamAddress = new TeamAddress
                                                            {
                                                                Box = model.TeamContact.TeamAddress.Box,
                                                                StreetName = model.TeamContact.TeamAddress.StreetName,
                                                                StreetNumber = model.TeamContact.TeamAddress.StreetNumber,
                                                                City = model.TeamContact.TeamAddress.City,
                                                                PostalCode = model.TeamContact.TeamAddress.PostalCode,
                                                                Province = model.TeamContact.TeamAddress.Province
                                                            }
                                    }
                };
                _dataSource.Save();
        }

        return View(model);
```

**Table Relationships**

```
-Team one-to-one TeamContact
-TeamContact one-to-on TeamAddress
```

**IDataSource Interface**

```
    IQueryable<Team> Teams { get; }        
    IQueryable<TeamAddress> TeamAddresses { get; }
    IQueryable<TeamContact> TeamContacts { get; }
    void Save();
```

**Context class**

```
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }        
    IQueryable<Team> IDataSource.Teams
    {
        get { return Teams; }
    }

    public DbSet<TeamAddress> TeamAddresses { get; set; }
    IQueryable<TeamAddress> IDataSource.TeamAddresses
    {
        get { return TeamAddresses; }
    }

    public DbSet<TeamContact> TeamContacts { get; set; }
    IQueryable<TeamContact> IDataSource.TeamContacts
    {
        get { return TeamContacts; }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

What am i missing to have my data saved to the database?

Comment: I don't see how you add your new entity to the context - something like `_dataSource.Teams.Add(team)`

Comment: @Pawel `Add()` is a method of ICollection and would work if entity Team had an Icollection property in another entity. eg: `public virtual ICollection<Team> Team{ get; set; }` Your suggestion will work when i write a create method for the Player entity which is being collected by the team entity.

Comment: I am talking about `Add()` exposed on `DbSet<Team> Teams` - if you don't add this how DbContext should know about this object? The only other way would be to add an entity that references the new Team entity you created but I don't see anything like that in your code.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks, wish there was a cheat sheet. Anyways, i have a difficulty adding that method unless i change my repository pattern. Any ideas on how i could add this without having to change much? This is the only pattern i know that works with auto migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any code in your controller that is actually adding the `Team` to your database. Right now you are simply creating a new Team object in memory and saving changes to your database. Nothing is actually being added to the database to save.

```
Team team = new Team
                {
                    .. the rest of your model building code here ..
                };

_dataSource.Teams.Add(team); // This adds the Team entity to the database
_dataSource.Save();
```

Comment: I tried that. `Add()` is a method of ICollection and would work if entity Team had an Icollection property in another entity. eg: `public virtual ICollection<Team> Team{ get; set; }` Your suggestion will work when i write a create method for the Player entity which is being collected by the team entity

Comment: @KomengeMwandila `Add()` is also a method of `DbSet`. See [the MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: Any ideas on how i would implement that little section. i have had no luck with what i have tried, unless i change my repository setup??

Comment: I think your problem was you were trying to use the `Add()` method on the `IQueryable<Team>` when you need to use it on the `DbSet<Team>`. You may need to change your repository set up because I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to use the `IQueryable<T>` properties for.

Comment: Sorry i took so long, but i made it work. Had to restructure my repository and also had to write separate save method for a set of entities which also included an add method. See the edit in your initial answer post